# RequestMapping in spring mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I am trying to understand requestmapping in spring mvc, I have an application, actually I am just getting started with spring mvc.

I have these two urls

The first one with a forward slash at the end seems to be working fine.
`http://localhost:8080/contactmanager/index/`

The second one without a forward slash at the end does not work

```
http://localhost:8080/contactmanager/index
```

This second one gives me the 'HTTP Status 404 -' error, how can I force the application to be appending a forwards slash at the end of the url?

The method in the controller looks like this

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map) {

    map.put("contact", new Contact());
    map.put("contactList", contactService.listContact());
    //org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    //org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    //org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    //org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    return "contact";
}
```

and my web.xml looks like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>contactmanager</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/contactmanager-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>contactmanager</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1428716 the issue is if I write the url with a forward slash (/) at the end like index/ , I get it working but when I omit the slash at the end just like index , then I get 404 , has it to do with the way may web.xml is configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using java configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig {}
```

or using XML configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

From [Spring's reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping):

> The above registers a **RequestMappingHandlerMapping**, a
>   RequestMappingHandlerAdapter, and an ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver
>   (among others) in support of processing requests with annotated
>   controller methods using annotations such as @RequestMapping ,
>   @ExceptionHandler, and others.

In `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` there is useful boolean flag - decription from Javadoc:

```
/**
 * Whether to match to URLs irrespective of the presence of a trailing slash.
 * If enabled a method mapped to "/users" also matches to "/users/".
 * <p>The default value is {@code true}.
*/
public void setUseTrailingSlashMatch(boolean useTrailingSlashMatch) {
   this.useTrailingSlashMatch = useTrailingSlashMatch;
}
```

Since this is enabled by default just make sure that your configuration uses `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.

If this doesn't help you, check that spring's default servlet is configured: `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` and try add to `web.xml`

```
<!-- Disables Servlet Container welcome file handling. Needed for compatibility with   Servlet 3.0 and Tomcat 7.0 -->
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file></welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I didnt have a clear mapping of the whole requesting mapping in spring mvc, now I understand, you can specify the mapping on the controller class or method and nesting in the method means you append the path on the class to the one in the method. Thanks for the lead

Comment: For those who use a configuration class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, override the method `configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer)` and set `configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);`.  The default value is `true`, as you've no doubt found out if you're reading this question and answer.